Sending data from server to a client with dynamic IP address in IoT system
I'm trying to design and implement an IoT system in which users would be able to control their smart devices (lightbulbs etc.) through smartphone application. The control messages flow would be like this: mobile app -> server -> hub device in user's home -> device to be controlled.
Now how can a server know where to forward the message if hubs have dynamic IP addresses ?
As suggested here in Peter Green's answer the clients would "need to establish a permanent TCP connection to the server and they need to periodically send a test/keepalive message to the server". These open connections would consume server's resources.
This is a university project so I don't expect more than a few hubs to be connected at the same time but I want my solution to be as real world as possible (with thousands of devices). Would permanent WebSocket connections be a good way to make communication between server and hubs happen ? And if yes, then how to make server (in Spring) to be able to handle all this connections ? (I know nothing about large scale computing) (I'm planning the server to work on AWS)

"These open connections would consume server's resources." How much? How heavy a tcp connection is? Let's make it heavier: a tls connection (you don't want to send unencrypted data)? Negligible. Don't think in terms of "high scale". High scale means tens of thousands of connections. You will never reach that, and you will waste a lot of time and sanity designing a scalable solution. Completely not worth it.

The only web app I've ever made was a simple web shop so I have no idea about how much work such server can handle at the same time. Your comment kinda calmed me down.

I'm pretty sure the idea of a permanent websocket connection is a non-starter.

Are you familiar with broadcasting on a local network? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcasting_(networking)

I'm sorry, somehow i can't understand what are you getting at @JimmyJames . How could I use local network broadcasting for communication between server and hubs ? A hub is in user's local network.

@Wonsz Oh sorry, I misread the question.  I thought you were trying to connect to the devices from the hub.  Never mind.

Do you have any requirements around a service level agreement (SLA)?  In other words, have you been given any guidance on the maximum amount of time between the request from the mobile app and it being executed at the home?

No, but of course I want it to work as fast as possible e.g. user clicks a button and lightbulb is lit without user experiencing any delay. I thought of the idea of hub sending requests in short time intervals to check if any control messages were sent to the server but it would create a huge network traffic i suppose.

Yes, you should establish a long living connection with the server.
Let's talk about numbers a bit. How much tcp connection weights? OS has to keep track of file descriptor, and some metadata. I don't know the exact number but let's be generous and say it is 100 bytes (I'm sure it is a lot less). Then we need tls, you don't want to communicate over non encrypted channel. Tls comes with additional overhead, in particular the initial handshake can be quite heavy (in order of kb). But once the connection is established it needs to hold a symmetric key, plus maybe some additional data. Let's be generous again and say it is 1kb.
For WebSockets this is even more, because it lives on top of tls. And it has additional overhead of HTTP stack. So let's be generous again and say that we pay 2kb of memory per connection. In reality this is a lot less.
This means you can easily manage hundreds of thousands of connections, at least in terms of memory.
What about CPU? Well, as far as I understand you want to push data to devices on users activity. This means that 99% of those connections, 99% of time will be idle. That's good, that means they won't eat much CPU. Of course you will need some ping/pong mechanism (to ensure these are alive) but that is not a big deal if not too often (say every 5s is probably fine, but YMMV).
And then there's network overhead. There isn't much difference between tls or WebSockets once they are established. WebSockets is a bit more convenient, it at least implements framing for you, in a standard way. But you still need a custom protocol on top of that. Here things matter slightly more. However a well crafted protocol, with proper compression will certainly work well. But even if you send JSON messages around, it will work fine as long as you don't flood the network with it. So focus more on messaging and network, rather than server's resources. Especially with IoT, because you won't have that much control over network.
From my experience I can tell you straight away: you are overthinking this. Do the simplest working solution and it will be fine. And if by chance you run out of server resources, then congratulations! You now have scale so big that you can actually hire professionals that will fix it for you. Or you can learn how to do this yourself. It's not really hard, you just need multiple servers that talk to each other in two directional way, sort of proxies. And a load balancer. But also setting this up properly, maintaining and monitoring is just pain in the a**. Avoid if possible.

There are existing commercial solutions. Basically a small piece of code hosted on the user's internet hub periodically calls the providers server and tells it the current dynamic IP address. Clients are allocated a URL on the provider's server. The cost is around $US15 per user per annum which may or may not blow your budget.
Log into your internet hub and look for a configuration option for dynamic IP or similar. Your hub may support several providers.

You're talking about dynamic DNS, right? If you do it that way, you also have to deal with the firewall and cgNAT

If I understood correctly, this would need port forwarding on user's router (I may be wrong) so if it was a real product the company would have to send technicians probably everytime someone buys a hub. I wanted to avoid this.

@Wonsz Yes your understanding is correct. Any solution that can call the client directly will perform well but will require non-trivial configuration.
